# Why is the destination folder in a meeting workspace document library defaulting to /1/?

Tags: 2010, document-library, file-upload, meeting-workspace

I created a meeting workspace with a document library in SharePoint 2010.  The dialog box for uploading a document has a folder option that I haven't seen in other SP sites.  The destination folder defaults to /1/ with a "choose folder" button.  However, if a contributor clears the "/1/" default before he uploads a document, he can't see it.

Can anyone tell me now to make the folder options work in the dialog box for uploading documents?

Comment: Related: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/19111/why-is-a-folder-automatically-created-named-1-in-document-libraries

Comment: Please don't add your name as a signature to posts as this doesn't provide valuable information. Your user name is already displayed on the post.